# Using selenium WebDriver to perform a click in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, safari

I have a button defined on a webpage as:

```
<div class="form-group mt-3 mb-1 d-grid">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            Login
    </button>
</div>
```

In Python, I have coded up like so...

```
browser = webdriver.Safari(options=Options)
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element("xpath","//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]").click()
```

I get the exception below...

```
in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

How do I automate the click on the login button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Safari(options=Options)
browser.get(url)
login_btn = browser.find_element("xpath","//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]")

login_btn.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Below works also browser.find_element("xpath","//button[@type='submit']").click()

Answer (score 0):

The exception you posted says you should wait for the element to be
clickable (ElementNotInteractableException)

To do the wait, try adding this to your code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

EW = 20  # EW stands for explicit_wait
WebDriverWait(browser, EW).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH,
         "//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]")
    )).click()
```